# Update array value in angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my Sample code :

```
var array_03 = [{'name':'Kapila','age':30}];
var array_04 = [{'name':'Saman','age':30}];    
$scope.userName_03 = array_03[0]['name']; // Kapila
$scope.userName_04 = array_04[0]['name']; // Saman
angular.isArray(array_03); // true
angular.isArray(array_04); // true

array_04[0]['name'] == $scope.userName_03; // <-- Problem here     

$scope.userName_05 = array_04[0]['name']; // <-- Hope to get 'Kapila' But Result 'Saman'
```

I Hope to $scope.userName_05 as 'Kapila' But Result 'Saman'

**array_04[0]['name'] == $scope.userName_03; // <-- Problem here**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
array_04[0]['name'] == $scope.userName_03; // <-- Problem here
```

In this line use **'='** instead of **'=='**
You are assigning the value so it must be **'='** *(assignment operator)*

Comment: array_04[0]['name'] = $scope.userName_03;      It's Working thanks